# Sending data to an array: Type mismatch VBA/Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a dynamic series of worksheets, each representing an individual work week, in a single workbook.
These worksheets have several drivers from which I am grabbing data and storing such in multiple arrays 0-13. These arrays then dump their data to sorted lists for output to a summary sheet. Data is broken down by date so that monthly statistics are possible.

Occasionally there are "additional" drivers. These drivers also need to have their data captured and summarised as well. Unlike the dedicated drivers, the "additional drivers" need to have their data broken down by vehicle type.

My conditions, checking for additional drivers and checking for truck type, work. My array for the additional drivers, does not. I am receiving a type mismatch error when the array attempts to store data.  I am very confused; as I have kept an identical format for the preceding arrays 0-9 (which all function and output normally--and are omitted from the code below)

I have checked the contents of the cells and those values are accurate. However, when I try to store such in the array I get a type mismatch.

What is causing the type mismatch error in this one array, and yet the others operate perfectly?

The actual line of code generating this error is noted in the code comments below:

```
Dim arTemp
Dim arTemp1
Dim arTemp10
Dim list As Object, list1 As Object, list10 As Object

Dim d As Date
Dim x As Long, y As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") 'Driver A
Set list1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") 'Driver B
Set list10 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") '5-Ton Extra Drivers

Dim Truck5T As String, Truck3T As String, TruckC As String, StringCheck As String
Truck5T = "5-Ton"

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "WE Jan 08" Then
        With ws
            For y = 3 To 7
                'Check for dates for each route
                d = DateSerial(Year(.Cells(3, y)), Month(.Cells(3, y)), 1)
                If list.containskey(d) Then
                    arTemp = list(d)
                    arTemp1 = list(d)
                    arTemp10 = list10(d)
                Else
                    ReDim arTemp(13)
                    ReDim arTemp1(13)
                    ReDim arTemp10(13)
                End If
                arTemp(0) = arTemp(0) + .Cells(4, y) 'Grab # Deliveries (AM)
                arTemp(1) = arTemp(1) + .Cells(5, y) 'Grab # of Pick Ups (AM)
                arTemp(2) = arTemp(2) + .Cells(6, y) 'Grab # of Tires (AM)
                arTemp(3) = arTemp(3) + .Cells(7, y) 'Grab Kilometres (AM)
                arTemp(4) = arTemp(4) + .Cells(8, y) 'Grab # of Deliveries (PM)
                arTemp(5) = arTemp(5) + .Cells(9, y) 'Grab # of Pick Ups (PM)
                arTemp(6) = arTemp(6) + .Cells(10, y) 'Grab # of Tires (PM)
                arTemp(7) = arTemp(7) + .Cells(11, y) 'Grab Kilometres (PM)
                arTemp(8) = arTemp(8) + .Cells(12, y) 'Grab # of Deliveries (Total)
                arTemp(9) = arTemp(9) + .Cells(13, y) 'Grab # of Pick Ups (Total)
                arTemp(10) = arTemp(10) + .Cells(14, y) 'Grab # of Tires (Total)
                arTemp(11) = arTemp(11) + .Cells(15, y) 'Grab Kilometres (Total)
                arTemp(12) = arTemp(12) + .Cells(16, y) 'Grab Hours
                arTemp(13) = arTemp(13) + 1
                list(d) = arTemp

                arTemp1(0) = arTemp1(0) + .Cells(4, y) 'Grab # Deliveries (AM)
                arTemp1(1) = arTemp1(1) + .Cells(5, y) 'Grab # of Pick Ups (AM)
                arTemp1(2) = arTemp1(2) + .Cells(6, y) 'Grab # of Tires (AM)
                arTemp1(3) = arTemp1(3) + .Cells(7, y) 'Grab Kilometres (AM)
                arTemp1(4) = arTemp1(4) + .Cells(8, y) 'Grab # of Deliveries (PM)
                arTemp(5) = arTemp1(5) + .Cells(9, y) 'Grab # of Pick Ups (PM)
                arTemp1(6) = arTemp1(6) + .Cells(10, y) 'Grab # of Tires (PM)
                arTemp1(7) = arTemp1(7) + .Cells(11, y) 'Grab Kilometres (PM)
                arTemp1(8) = arTemp1(8) + .Cells(12, y) 'Grab # of Deliveries (Total)
                arTemp1(9) = arTemp1(9) + .Cells(13, y) 'Grab # of Pick Ups (Total)
                arTemp1(10) = arTemp1(10) + .Cells(14, y) 'Grab # of Tires (Total)
                arTemp1(11) = arTemp1(11) + .Cells(15, y) 'Grab Kilometres (Total)
                arTemp1(12) = arTemp1(12) + .Cells(16, y) 'Grab Hours
                arTemp1(13) = arTemp1(13) + 1
                list1(d) = arTemp1

                    If .Cells(84, 2) <> "" Then
                        StringCheck = Left(.Cells(84, 2), 5)
                        If StringCheck = Truck5T Then
                            '5-ton (UpperL)
                            'first line below generates the type mismatch (cell value is what is expected from the worksheet)
                            arTemp10(0) = arTemp10(0) + .Cells(84 + 2, y) 'Grab # Deliveries (AM)
                            arTemp10(1) = arTemp10(1) + .Cells(84 + 3, y) 'Grab # of Pick Ups (AM)
                            arTemp10(2) = arTemp10(2) + .Cells(84 + 4, y) 'Grab # of Tires (AM)
                            arTemp10(3) = arTemp10(3) + .Cells(84 + 5, y) 'Grab Kilometres (AM)
                            arTemp10(4) = arTemp10(4) + .Cells(84 + 6, y) 'Grab # of Deliveries (PM)
                            arTemp10(5) = arTemp10(5) + .Cells(84 + 7, y) 'Grab # of Pick Ups (PM)
                            arTemp10(6) = arTemp10(6) + .Cells(84 + 8, y) 'Grab # of Tires (PM)
                            arTemp10(7) = arTemp10(7) + .Cells(84 + 9, y) 'Grab Kilometres (PM)
                            arTemp10(8) = arTemp10(8) + .Cells(84 + 10, y) 'Grab # of Deliveries (Total)
                            arTemp10(9) = arTemp10(9) + .Cells(84 + 11, y) 'Grab # of Pick Ups (Total)
                            arTemp10(10) = arTemp10(10) + .Cells(84 + 12, y) 'Grab # of Tires (Total)
                            arTemp10(11) = arTemp10(11) + .Cells(84 + 13, y) 'Grab Kilometres (Total)
                            arTemp10(12) = arTemp10(12) + .Cells(84 + 14, y) 'Grab Hours
                            arTemp10(13) = arTemp10(13) + 1
                            list10(d) = arTemp10
                        End If
                  End If
             Next
        End With
    End If
Next

With Worksheets("Summary")
    .Cells.Delete

    For x = 0 To list.Count - 1 'Driver A
        d = list.getkey(x)
        .Cells(x + 43, 1) = Year(d)
        .Cells(x + 43, 2) = Month(d)
        .Cells(x + 43, 3) = list(d)(0)
        .Cells(x + 43, 4) = list(d)(1)
        .Cells(x + 43, 5) = list(d)(2)
        .Cells(x + 43, 6) = list(d)(3)
        .Cells(x + 43, 7) = list(d)(4)
        .Cells(x + 43, 8) = list(d)(5)
        .Cells(x + 43, 9) = list(d)(6)
        .Cells(x + 43, 10) = list(d)(7)
        .Cells(x + 43, 11) = list(d)(8)
        .Cells(x + 43, 12) = list(d)(9)
        .Cells(x + 43, 13) = list(d)(10)
        .Cells(x + 43, 14) = list(d)(11)
        .Cells(x + 43, 15) = list(d)(12)
    Next
 For x = 0 To list.Count - 1 'Driver A
        d = list.getkey(x)
        .Cells(x + 43, 1) = Year(d)
        .Cells(x + 43, 2) = Month(d)
        .Cells(x + 43, 3) = list1(d)(0)
        .Cells(x + 43, 4) = list1(d)(1)
        .Cells(x + 43, 5) = list1(d)(2)
        .Cells(x + 43, 6) = list1(d)(3)
        .Cells(x + 43, 7) = list1(d)(4)
        .Cells(x + 43, 8) = list1(d)(5)
        .Cells(x + 43, 9) = list1(d)(6)
        .Cells(x + 43, 10) = list1(d)(7)
        .Cells(x + 43, 11) = list1(d)(8)
        .Cells(x + 43, 12) = list1(d)(9)
        .Cells(x + 43, 13) = list1(d)(10)
        .Cells(x + 43, 14) = list1(d)(11)
        .Cells(x + 43, 15) = list1(d)(12)
    Next
  For x = 0 To list.Count - 1 'Additional Drivers: 5-Ton
        d = list.getkey(x)
        .Cells(x + 193, 1) = Year(d)
        .Cells(x + 193, 2) = Month(d)
        .Cells(x + 193, 3) = list10(d)(0)
        .Cells(x + 193, 4) = list10(d)(1)
        .Cells(x + 193, 5) = list10(d)(2)
        .Cells(x + 193, 6) = list10(d)(3)
        .Cells(x + 193, 7) = list10(d)(4)
        .Cells(x + 193, 8) = list10(d)(5)
        .Cells(x + 193, 9) = list10(d)(6)
        .Cells(x + 193, 10) = list10(d)(7)
        .Cells(x + 193, 11) = list10(d)(8)
        .Cells(x + 193, 12) = list10(d)(9)
        .Cells(x + 193, 13) = list10(d)(10)
        .Cells(x + 193, 14) = list10(d)(11)
        .Cells(x + 193, 15) = list10(d)(12)
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Try debugging your code.  E.g. What is the original value of `arTemp10(0)`?

Comment: What's the value of `list10(d)`? By my read it should be an empty `Variant`, not an array.

Comment: The original value of arTemp10(0) is nothing--the type mismatch is at:
    arTemp10(0) = arTemp10(0) + .Cells(84 + 2, y) 
Which is the first entry into the array. The data in the cell is fine. It's simply not getting passed to the array.

The value of list10(0) would become the values of arTemp10(0) through to arTemp10(13) of which 13 is a counter and the remainder are whatever data is in the worksheet cells.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here...

> ```
> If List.containskey(d) Then
>     arTemp10 = list10(d)  
> Else
>     ReDim arTemp10(13)
> End If
> ```

...specifically the assignment `arTemp10 = list10(d)`.  You create a new `SortedList` here...

> ```
> Set list10 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") '5-Ton Extra Drivers
> ```

...but never add any items to it.  An empty `SortedList` will return `Empty` when you pass *any* index to it:

```
Set foo = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
Debug.Print TypeName(foo(42))  'Prints "Empty"
```

That means this line of code...

> ```
> arTemp10(0) = arTemp10(0) + .Cells(84 + 2, y) 'Grab # Deliveries (AM)
> ```

...is equivalent to trying to index a variable that isn't an array:

```
Dim arTemp10 As Variant  'arTemp10 is implicitly Variant in your code.
Debug.Print arTemp10(0)  'Type mismatch.
```

It's unclear from your question what *should* be in `list10`, but you need to initialize it before you try to use its members as arrays.

**Edit:**

Now that the more of the code is available, the error is still here:

> ```
> If list.containskey(d) Then
>     arTemp = list(d)
>     arTemp10 = list10(d)
> Else
>     ReDim arTemp(13)
>     ReDim arTemp10(13)
> End If
> ```

There isn't a test to see if `list10` contains an item `d`.  This most likely needs to be split into 2 conditions:

```
If list.containskey(d) Then
    arTemp = list(d)
Else
    ReDim arTemp(13)
End If

If list10.containskey(d) Then
    arTemp10 = list10(d)
Else
    ReDim arTemp10(13)
End If
```

Comment: I do not understand--in so far as that, arTemp through to arTemp9, which are defined and loaded with data the same way(which you indicate is incorrect in the above code), all function. This would imply that there is another issue at work.

The items to list10 would normally be loaded at this point:

Comment: @WarOrdos - In that case you need to remove the line `Set list10 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") `.  That's setting `list10` to a ***new*** `SortedList`.

Comment: Sorry hit enter by mistake..

    list10(d) = arTemp10 'is where the data would be loaded to the list from the array

However, I am getting, in this array and this array only, the type mismatch prior to data being stored and then transferred to the list.

Comment: @WarOrdos - If there's code missing between `Set list10 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")` and `arTemp10 = list10(d)` , then edit the question to include it.  Otherwise, see the comment above.

Comment: The only omitted code, as originally noted in the question, is that of the other array's (arTemp through to arTemp9) which all function perfectly).

I will edit to include another example which works fine to illustrate.

Comment: @WarOrdos - The root cause of the issue is still the same.  If you attempt to index `list10(d)` and that item doesn't exist, you get a type mismatch because it returns `Empty`, not an array.  I'd suggest adding `If IsEmpty(arTemp10) Then Stop` immediately below `arTemp10 = list10(d)`.  That should kick you into the debugger.  From that point, you'll have to track down the logic error that is giving you an empty `Variant` back.

Comment: Except that the same code works for arTemp through to arTemp9. Thus the question remains, why would this same format work for those 10 and not this one? Your answer would indicate a systemic problem with all the array's and that is not the reality of the situation. Hence, what is different with arTemp10 relative to the others?

Comment: @WarOrdos - You only check `If list.containskey(d) Then`.  You don't check `If list10.containskey(d)`.  So you get an empty item.

Comment: The date range is the same for all array's/lists. Thus I only need to check for the one, as it's the same for all. That said, list10(d) is not the problem, as far as I can tell, since it's the initial loading of arTemp10(0) that is causing the type mismatch. This occurs prior to anything going into list10(d). List10(d) is going to be empty because arTemp10 is not getting passed any data due to the type mismatch.

Comment: @WarOrdos - No, `list10(d)` is empty because you only add members to it if `If .Cells(84, 2) <> ""`.  You assign `arTemp10` from it in ***every case***. I'd take the advice in the comment by MátéJuhász and step through this in the debugger so you see what is happening.

Comment: 1. I have used the debugger already.
2. Why does there need to be any test for list10(d) when the error precedes any calls to list10(d)? This does not make sense--it's like the chicken and the egg in a way. The issue is with arTemp10 and the initial acquisition of data.

As I have mentioned ALL the other arrays/lists work with code identical to what you see above. If list10(d) needs to be checked, as you've suggested then why do I not need to check for list2(d), list3(d)...list9(d)? The condition chain for list.containskey(d) is applied to ALL the array's/lists and they function.

Comment: I'll go ahead and add another edit to the code so you can, perhaps, see why I'm confused frustrated with your responses thus far, in that, if I need to check for list10.containskey(d) then why do I not need to do so for the other 10 arrays?

Comment: @WarOrdos - When you were debugging, did you ***check*** to see if `list10(d)` was empty?  Note that my answers are based on the code that you have variously chosen to include.  If you have more code that wasn't included, ***post everything*** .  To do anything else is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: As I noted originally, the only code not included is the repetition of the earlier array's/lists. (you can see the format going from arTemp to arTemp1 etc. This continues through to arTemp9, likewise for the printing setups for the lists. There is no sense in posting repetitive code that has no impact on the issue at hand. There is no other code operating--additional functional arrays/lists would have no impact.
Now, I have made clear that the other array's/lists function as intended. arTemp10 does not. I have asked you specifically, why this array/list would need extra conditions.

Comment: Thus far I have not received an answer, instead I have received a frustrated attack for not including repetitive coding that has no impact on the case at hand, and was already mentioned at the top of this comment chain.